# Use domain in act_window .Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

I worked with `'stock.picking'` model  I added a button in the form view.
When I click in this button , I want to create a new record in `'helpdesk.ticket'` model , with domain of field `'product_id'` same of list of products in stock move lines.

Here is my code , I tried it with domain , but doesn't work .

```
def create_ticket(self):
    helpdesk_ticket_id = self.env['helpdesk.ticket'].create({
        'name': 'Ticket'
    })
    return {
        'name': _('New'),
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'helpdesk.ticket',
        'views': [(self.env.ref('helpdesk.helpdesk_ticket_view_form').id, 'form'),
                  (self.env.ref('helpdesk.helpdesk_tickets_view_tree').id, 'tree'),
                  ],
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_id': helpdesk_ticket_id.id,
        'domain': [('product_id', 'in', self.move_ids_without_package.product_id)],
    }
```

Any help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `product_ids` through the context:

```
'context': {'product_ids': self.move_ids_without_package.product_id.ids},
```

and use a function to compute the `product_id` field domain:

```
class HelpDeskTicket(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'helpdesk.ticket'

    @api.model
    def _get_product_domain(self):
        if 'product_ids' in self.env.context:
            return [('id', 'in', self.env.context['product_ids'])]
        return []

    product_id = fields.Many2one(domain=_get_product_domain)
```

Comment: when I tried this I got empty domain in product_id although I have 2 product ids when printing context.get('product_ids', [])

Comment: I updated my answer to return a default domain when `product_ids` is not available (creating a Ticket in the form view). I tested it on the OCA ``helpdesk_mgmt`` model and when the form view is opened with ``create_ticket`` button the products are filtered

Comment: The previous domain definition is usually used in wizards

Comment: it works with your solution , Thank you .